# How can i transfer fund to a specific user by getting his/her userID? (Codeigniter)

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Newbie here. My target is to get the `ID` of the person that I'm going to transfer with. For example: His `userID` = 4. The `userID` in my database `userID` column should be = 4. I have provided screenshot below for better explanation. Thank you in advance

https://prnt.sc/w9piat << Screenshot of my problem and my target

**Views**:

```
<button data-id="<?php echo $rows->userID; ?>" class=" fundTable btn btn-success btn-sm text-bold " type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fundModal">
  <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd mr-1"></i> <?php echo $rows->userID; ?>FUND
</button>
```

**Controller**:

```
public function form_validation()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("amount","Amount", 'required|numeric');
        
        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            
            $ref= $this->session->userdata('userID') + time ();
            
            
            $data = array(
                'userID' => $this->session->userdata('uid'),
                'transactionSource' => 'fund',
                'refNumber' => 'FI' . $ref,
                "amount" =>$this->input->post("amount"),
                "transType" =>"in",
                
                
            );
            $ref= $this->session->userdata('userID') + time ();
            
            $data1 = array(
                'userID' => $this->session->userdata('uid'),
                "transactionSource" => 'fund',
                "refNumber" => 'FO' . $ref,
                "amount" =>$this->input->post("amount"),
                "transType" =>"out",
                
                
            );
            
            
            $this->networks->insert_data($idata, $idata1);
            
          
            
            redirect(base_url() . "network/agents");
        }
        
        else
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        
    }
```

**Model**:

```
function insert_data($data,$data1)
    {
        

        
        $sql1 = "select * from transaction_ledger where userID = ?  order by ledgerID desc limit 0,1";
        $Q1 = $this->db->query($sql1, $data['userID']);
        
        $R1 = $Q1->row_array();
        $ref= $this->session->userdata('userID') + time ();
        
        $idata = array(
            'userID' => $data['userID'],
            'transactionSource' => 'Fund',
            'transType' => 'out',
            'refNumber' => 'FO' . $ref,
            'amount' => $data['amount'],
            'currentBalance' => $R1['currentBalance'] - $data['amount'],
            'previousBalance' => $R1['currentBalance'],
            
        );
        
        $this->db->insert('transaction_ledger', $idata);
        
       
        //update current wallet
        $sqlUpdate = "update users set currentPoints = '".$idata['currentBalance']."', dateUpdated = '".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."'where userID = ?";
        
        $this->db->query($sqlUpdate, $data['userID']);
        
       
        
        //update you will get the fund
        
        
        
        $idata1 = array(
          //  'userID' => $data['userID'],  (My target is, the ID of the person that i will transfer the fund. How can i get his/her ID? 
            'transactionSource' => 'Fund',
            'transType' => 'in',
            'refNumber' => 'FI' . $ref,
            'amount' => $data['amount'],
            'currentBalance' => $R1['currentBalance'] + $data['amount'],
            'previousBalance' => $R1['currentBalance'],
            
        );
        $this->db->insert('transaction_ledger', $idata1);
        
        $sqlUpdate = "update users set currentPoints = '".$idata1['currentBalance']."', dateUpdated = '".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."'where userID=0";
        
        $this->db->query($sqlUpdate, $data['userID']);
    }
       

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your modal form add a hidden field that holds the ID of the user you want to fund. Every time you click the "Fund" button you get the ID of that button then add it on the modal form hidden field and in that way you can pass that value together with the amount.

```
<!-- 5 is the id person that going to transfer with -->
<button data-id="7" class="showmodal" class="fundTable btn btn-success btn-sm text-bold">
  <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd mr-1"></i> 5 FUND
</button>

<div id="fundModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="#">
          <input type="text" id="usertransferid"> 
          <input type="number" id="amount">
        </form>
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can test it here https://jsfiddle.net/renzuii/tvnjf172/

Comment: Wow. This is a very great suggestion. I'll work it out. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome :) just mark this as correct answer if it will work on your side ^_^

Comment: Is it okay to ask you if I encounter some errors while working on your suggestions?

Comment: Hi I added a jsfiddle and edited my answer hope that will help :)

Comment: Hello, I'm grateful for this one. I'll apply this now. Thank you again.